# UI Automator Viewer finds elements inconsisently

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have a weird issue while working with the UI Automator Viewer. The problem is that I get inconsistent result when doing "Device Screenshot" (uiautomator dump). So in some cases, I get all the elements(nodes) but in some cases I get only some of them, generally the basic whole page view without the textviews and buttons on it.

To make things even more challenging, it looks like it happens absolutely random. So I can click on screenshot/dump button multiple times in a row and get different results while the application on the device (or emulator) stays untouched!

I have experienced the same issue on both, a real device and an emulator. The application that am working on is a hybrid application which does not provide WEBVIEW handles.

What can possibly cause such behavior?

Comment: `So I can click on screenshot/dump button multiple times in a row and get random results while the application on the device (or emulator) stays untouched!` correct me if I am wrong, you mean for the same View on the application you would get inconsistent UIAutomator dump, is it?

Comment: @nullpointer Hi, yes. I should have probably used the word "different" instead "random" though. So when I have my application running on a real device or emulator and I have the UI Automator Viewer window open, I repeatedly click on "Device Screenshot" button and the node information that I get on the left side is different from time to time.

Comment: can u pls add a screenshot of the app screen with uiautomator dump for any guesses

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue @EugeneS? I am stuck at the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274388/uiautomator-bug-while-inspecting-webview-elements

Comment: @nullpointer this is the exact same issue that I am facing

Comment: @Rashmi.B Unfortunately not. Actually I am really surprised to discover that this issue is so uncommon. I would think that I will get at least some clue but this is just some kind of mystery at the moment. Please update me if you do find answer. Cheers