# UiAutomator bug while inspecting WebView elements

Tags: android, webview, appium, android-uiautomator

I have recently started automation testing in android and was using UiAutomator tool for inspecting UI elements. Surprisingly, I came across two different responses for Webview elements for the same screen and same device [Genymotion MotoX 4.4.4]. Attached are the screenshots for the same. We all know that appium has an issue with inspecting webview elements who do not carry "setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled" to true. Is this a bug in UiAutomator?
[image: Screen displaying child elements of webview]

[image: Screen without WebView children]

Answer (score 3):

> We all know that appium has an issue with inspecting webview elements
> who do not carry "setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled" to true. Is this a
> bug in UiAutomator?

**NO**, its not a bug. Its an **IMPLEMENTATION** as is. Unless the `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` is set to `true`, you cannot debug or access any elements inside a webview.

To quote from [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean))

> **void setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled (boolean enabled)**
>
> *Enables
> debugging of web contents (HTML / CSS / JavaScript) loaded into any
> WebViews of this application. This flag can be enabled in order to
> facilitate debugging of web layouts and JavaScript code running inside
> WebViews. Please refer to WebView documentation for the debugging
> guide. The default is false.*

You might be interested into these as well :

[Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Comment: Appreciate your answer @Nullpointer but my concern here is I am not accessable to the source code of the app. Firstly, we are testing only the APK. So we cannot set any flag as of now. Secondly, the varied elements that we receive via UiAutomator. And when I say BUG, I rather meant it for UiAutomator and not appium :)

Comment: @Rashmi.B : why do you find it a bug? and if thats the question it shall rather be posted on some community and not SO.

Comment: The reason I posted here was it has a wider technical audience from different streams. With forums, the discussions halts abruptly and I am in dire need of help to parse web elements

Comment: @Rashmi.B : well I don't find it a bug, so if you do, you've got to prove points on the code. For which some research over the UIAutomator implementation would be great to see in the updated question from you.

Comment: The reason why @Rashmi.B understandably thinks it's a bug is because the same app, on the same device, on the same screen sometimes shows the Views and sometimes it doesn't. I think it's a bug too.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano : probably to my understanding what you're stating is different to OP's question.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano got me right. That is exactly what I am facing. Same device, same app, same screen and different outputs from uiAutomator

Comment: @Rashmi.B : if thats what you mean && also by 'same app' you mean an app with `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled=true` in both the cases.  then certainly it could be a bug. [assuming device is also same]

Comment: @nullpointer there's no "in both cases..." because there is **only one** case.

Comment: @nullpointer that's the catch here. I am automating an already existing app where the developer hasn't set setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled=true, which is why I am not able inspect elements under webview. But with this issue in UiAutomator, it displays the child elements once and the other instance it doesn't

Comment: Whilst the answer is interesting, it doesn't address the crux of the issue. The screen shots clearly show UI Automater bug. I got here because of this exact behaviour and will be testing out genymotion.