# how to find element through appium when The UI Automation View don't provide element information

Tags: selenium, appium

I am unable to identify element using xpath. The  UI Automation View don't provide the element detail information.

I want to click the link on the email content.But there is no link element information.

Please help me. I am struck here.
 UI Automation screenshot:
[image]

Below is the page source:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35284193/1119381

Comment: Please mark an answer here as applicable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch the context for handling webview autoamation.

   ```
   driver.context("WEBVIEW"); //replace with your webview context
   ```
2. Try accessing using the x-path, css, class or simply by

   ```
   findElement(By.id("message_content"));
   ```

Comment: how is that going to help to identify the elements with the UIAutomator? He still needs to be able to do that to know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use chrome browser for inspecting the web view embedded in Android application. Official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?utm_source=dcc#debugging-webviews)

However, there might be a slight issue related to your problem. The thing is to debug a web view embedded in Android application, the web view itself should allow debugging. i.e. the web views object element needs to  be changed in the source code. **cached reference [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y4A7hD66yskJ:https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in), they have not mentioned this in the updated document.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

I am not sure if the email application has this enable or not. If you have the source code update the object as mentioned in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use chromes adb plugin to view the web view elements and to perform actions in web view use switch to context , after performing your actions in web view switch context back to native view